# How to use serverless-openapi-documentation with serverless Typescript template?

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework, serverless, openapi, aws-serverless

The issue is the following:

I aim to document a AWS serverless API using [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) framework with the [open API](https://github.com/temando/serverless-openapi-documentation) plugin for API documentation.

The issue I am facing is that the **Serverless** configuration created on *serverless.ts* file do not have a documentation field, it only has this definition:

```
interface Http {
    path: string;
    method: string;
    cors?: boolean | HttpCors;
    private?: boolean;
    async?: boolean;
    authorizer?: HttpAuthorizer;
    request?: HttpRequestValidation;
}
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create **Serverless** project with *Typescript* template:

  $ sls create -t aws-nodejs-typescript --path testName -n appName
- Add openapi plugin

  ```
  plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-openapi-documentation'],
  ```
- Replace functions section on *serverless.ts* with this:

  ```
  functions: {
    hello: {
      handler: 'handler.hello',
      events: [
        {
          http: {
            method: 'get',
            path: 'hello',
            documentation: {
              summary: "Create something"
            },
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ```

An error on the *documentation* line such as this will appear:

> Type '{ http: { method: string; path: string; }; documentation: { summary: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'documentation' does not exist in type 'Event'.

However, if instead of using the typescript template(i.e.: aws-nodejs-typescript) we use yml template(i.e.: aws-python) the documentation key can be added and the open API plugin works properly.

Does it means Open API plugin do not support Typescript yet? or rather, I am missing any configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is generated from typescript linting, and not from the serverless-openapi-documentation plugin.

Comment: While that's true @BennyThomas, adding @ts-ignore then results in the `serverless openapi generate` command throwing the error: `"service" property is missing in serverless.ts`. Has anyone encountered a solution?